# Where does the "export" command come from?

Tags: bash, utilities

Why doesn't the `whereis` command give any information about the `export` command? How does the `export` command work even if the shell path variable is set to null?

Comment: `whereis` is a nonstandard and not very useful command. `type` is better, because it is a builtin and should usually tell you how a command is resolved -- as a builtin, function, or non-builtin. Unfortunately POSIX has little to say about the details of `type`, so you have to check your shell's manual for what options it supports. `whence` is another command used by some shells and is similar to `type`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`whereis` doesn't show you a binary for `export` because it's a shell builtin. You can find it in the bash man page. As it's a builtin, not a binary, the shell doesn't search the `PATH` for it, so it will work regardless of the current path. Incidentally, this is why you are advised to use `type` to see what is being executed when you give a command:

```
$ which export
$ whereis export
$ type export
export is a shell builtin
```

Comment: @Kevin Where could I get information about built in `export`. What are the other built ins?

Comment: If you look at `man bash`, you'll see probably see BASH BUILTIN COMMANDS near the top.

Comment: @user3539 you can see all the builtins in bash's man page, or the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: For documentation about a specific bash command, use `help`: `help export`. Also, `type -a` shows you all the ways the command is found (alias/function/builtin/external)

Comment: Locally, you can browse them via ```man bash-builtins```